# How do I query a Realm object from a reference in another object?

Tags: swift, realm

```
class Person: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}
class Address: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var line1: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var line2: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var city: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var state: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var country: String = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}
class AssignedPersonAddress: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var person: Person!
  @objc dynamic var address: Address!
  @objc dynamic var type: String = "" // 'Home', 'Work', etc...

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

In order to record the type of address e.g. 'Home', 'Work', etc. the third table AssignedPersonAddress is required.

```
Person -* AssignedPersonAddress *- Address
```

How can I get an array (List) of the people associated with a particular address ?

```
let address = SomeAddress
```

This next line never returns any records even though database has records for the address - correction - I have to subscribe to the query and wait for notifications before any records become visible.

```
let assignedPersonAddresses = realm.objects(AssignedPersonAddress.self).filter("address == %@", address!)
```

Actually the line above throws an error about serialising a reference to an object but the following works

```
let assignedPersonAddresses = realm.objects(AssignedPersonAddress.self).filter("address.id == %@", address.id!)
```

It is also necessary to subscribe to notifications and only attempt to reference the results once the change notifications have been received.  And then I figured I could `flatMap{$0.person}` the results to get just the list of `Person`s - but that doesn't really work unless the `tableView` data is reloaded completely each time.

```
let peopleAtAddress = ??
```

Typical SQL would be something like:

```
"select * from Person where id in (select distinct(personId) from AssignedPersonAddress where address = selectedAddress)"
```

EDIT:

For now I have added a List of people to the Address object in the model which gets updated any time there is a change to the AssignedPersonAddress records.

Comment: you forget to specify primary keys for objects:
    `override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }`

Comment: These were just intended as object to illustrate the relationships so I never included the primary keys but I have corrected the question to include these primary keys.

Comment: You want to select people who have the same address in terms of name or what ??

Comment: Each person can have multiple associations with the same or different addresses.  e.g. home address, work address etc.  stored in the AssignedPersonAddress objects.   `Person -* AssignedPersonAddress *-Address`.  So for a given address I want the list of people who can be found at that address - typical SQL would be something like `"select distinct(person) from AssignedPersonAddress where address = selectedAddress"`

Comment: you have empty list because predicate is using primary key for comparison of addresses. And in your case every instance of `Address` have different id: `@objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString`
Identical address should have the same `id`, so you can get the list with values.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald You can try this             `let persons = realm.objects(AssignedPersonAddress.self).filter(NSPredicate(format:"address.id == %@", "1")).map({$0.person})`

Comment: @a.masri thanks but that returns an Array and not a result set so you can't subscribe to automatic change notifications - or can you?

Answer (score 0):

If do you need `Person` type of `Results<Person>` you can try this code

```
  let realm = try! Realm()

    var notificationToken: NotificationToken?


  try!  realm.write {

    let addressList  = realm.objects(AssignedPersonAddress.self)
    let personsId:[String] = addressList.filter({$0.id == "1"}).map({$0.person.id})
    let persons = realm.objects(Person.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "(id IN %@)",personsId))

   notificationToken =  addressList.realm?.observe({ (note, realm) in
    ......
    let personsId:[String] = addressList.filter({$0.id == "1"}).map({$0.person.id})

    let persons = realm.objects(Person.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "(id IN %@)",personsId))

    .....
    })


    }
```

Comment: OK, but how would i get notifications about changes if the AssignedPersonsAddress records get modified.

Comment: Do you need notification change to  person or  AssignedPersonsAddress ?

Comment: The screen displays the people associated with the address, so any changes to the AssignedPersonsAddress objects may change the array [personId] - which in turn may affect the list of people associated with the address.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald my answer modified  check it